# How to draw a line from slice of a pie chart to its related title using coreplot in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot, pie-chart

Here I stuck with a problem in drawing the pie chart using coreplot in iphone sdk.

Actually my problem is to represent a line between each slice and the title of that slice I searched for the properties but I didn't found.

Anyone's help will be deeply appreciated.

Thank you all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing like that built into Core Plot currently. You could make a subclass of CPTTextLayer that draws the connecting line in addition to the text and use that to make custom data labels.